# User specific storage backends in Django

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-storage

Use case: I want to develop a Django app that supports a collaborative workflow of multiple users. Users shall be invited to review files in an order defined by the uploading user. For this the file is uploaded to the app and users are invited. Multiple users belong to one organization. There are several organization. Files uploaded by an organization user to the app shall be stored in a space owned/controlled by the organization (“bring your own storage”), e.g an existing GoogleDrive or Dropbox. The storage target is configured by the first user of a new organization (target url, oauth token).

Question: is it possible to switch the storage backend of Django based on information related to the user uploading a new file, e.g. the users organization?

Comment: For the file, have you tried making the `upload_to` path dynamic based on the user? Does that seem like a workaround to you?

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but as far as I know this function just returns a path. I also have to establish the connection and authorize during this operation